# Sobre Expressão Regular em PHP - Como Pegar Parte de Um Texto?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Estou tendo dificuldade para pegar parte de um texto de uma pagina no [WikiPedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org).
Consigo pegar o titulo dessa forma:

```
$content = 
     file_get_contenst("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserva%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_natureza");

preg_match("/< title>(.*?)<\/title>/",$content,$title);
```

O que não estou conseguido é pegar o conteúdo que vai de `<div id="content" class="mw-body" role="main">` até `<span class="mw-headline" id="Ver_tamb.C3.A9m">Ver também</span>`

Não entendo porque não funciona, já tentei de diversas formas.

Comment: faz com explode
da um explode na primeira parte dai vc pega o array[1] e depois da um explode ate onde vc quer q pega e pega o array 0

Comment: O problema é que essa expressão não está pegando nenhum conteúdo.    Estou começando a achar que o preg_match não consegue pegar conteúdo muito grande, ou então não sei o que está havendo

Comment: Falta colocar na pergunta o trecho do source a ser pego, e explicar as regras para pegar. Da forma como está, não dá para responder com segurança.

Comment: Não sei as regras para pegar. Como disse o trecho que quero pegar vai de <div id="content" class="mw-body" role="main"> até <span class="mw-headline" id="Ver_tamb.C3.A9m">Ver também</span> a fonte é $content = 
  file_get_contenst("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserva%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_natureza");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Não seria melhor usar `DomDocument`?

Na minha humilde opinião, qualquer recurso que já exista para resolver um problema, esse deve ser o escolhido. Creio que usar expressões regulares para casos como o seu vai dar muito trabalho.

Então eu recomendo a utilização de `DomDocument`, que tem como finalidade representar uma entidade HTML ou XML.

Veja um exemplo de como poderia ser feito:

```
$content = 
 file_get_contents("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserva%C3%A7%C3%A3o_da_natureza")

$doc = new DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTML($content);


$titleTag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);

// Pega o título da página

$title = $titleTag ? $titleTag->nodeValue : null;

// Pega o valor da div#content, porém somente texto

$body = $doc->getElementById('content')->nodeValue;
```

Observe que o método `nodeValue` retornará somente o texto, removendo assim todas as tags presentes dentro de `#content`.

Se for necessário obter o texto com as tags, use o método `saveXml` para resolver o problema:

```
 $bodyWithTags = $doc->saveXml($doc->getElementById('content'));
```

## Atualização

Se você deseja uma maneira reutilizável de pegar somente o título da página, você pode criar uma função:

```
/**
 * Obtém o título da tag <title> de uma url
 * 
 * @param string $url
 * @return string|null
 * */
function  url_get_title($url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($url);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    @$doc->loadHTML($content);

    $titleTag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0);

    if ($titleTag) {
        return $titleTag->nodeValue;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Sendo assim, quando quisesse obter o título da página, bastaria fazer assim:

```
url_get_title('http://www.google.com.br'); // string (Google)
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO**: Sempre que você for usar `file_get_contents` para capturar o conteúdo de uma url, lembre-se que você sempre é obrigado a informar o esquema da mesma (http ou https). Se não fizer isso, o PHP vai tentar abrir o caminho de um arquivo. Mesmo sendo uma requisição feita para o próprio domínio é necessário incluir o esquema.

Comment: Amigo @wallace-maxters se você pudesse ajudar com este código, seria de grande valia, estou a tempos buscando como ler o title de um site para salvar no banco de dados, só preciso saber como pegar o title e o colocar em uma variável para o salvar, este seu código é bem linpo e bonito mas não consegui fazer funcionar, poderia simplificar e colocar um exemplo quando tiver tempo? muito grato.

Comment: o código parcial que tenho é este |       $domdocument = new DOMDocument();
      @$domdocument -> loadHTMLFile(urldecode($strri_array));
      $domxpath = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
      $title_path = $domxpath -> query("//title") -> item(0) -> nodeValue;

Comment: Qual é a dúvida, jovem? Quer usar pegar o título baseado nesse código que está me passando?

Comment: quando pús o comentário você atualizou sua resposta, é o que está na sua resposta mesmo que desejo, funcionou muito bem. muito grato, abusando um pouco, se souber pegar informação de pedágio com a matrix do google maps api rsrs

Comment: aparentemente ele não funciona se eu tentar pegar de um domínio dentro do mesmo servidor que o domínio que estou colocando o código né? tenho dois domínios direcionados dentro do mesmo host e quando tento pegar o title de qualquer um deles, tenho erro Warning: file_get_contents(http://itpin.tk/): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/u915144746/public_html/Plugins/entry.php on line 9, no caso, como seria um if(title) { ok } else { sem title } para colocar no lugar?

Comment: @flourigh o php trata  urls diferentemente de arquivos quando você usa `file_get_contents`. Não é que não funcione no mesmo servidor, é que você não especificou o `http` antes.

Comment: na verdade, está com http sim, Warning: file_get_contents(http://itpin.tk/): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/u915144746/public_html/Plugins/entry.php on line 9, o stackoverflow está removendo

Comment: Tá dando redirecionamento.  Leia atentamente o erro que está sendo exibido e tente resolvê-lo. Se não entender sobre o problema, pesquise na internet ou mesmo faça uma pergunta no site. Não há limites para fazer perguntas aqui, desde que elas atendam às regras do site.

Comment: entendi, então pode ser por que eu tenho um código que verifica de qual url o index está sendo acessado para abrir o programa correto, 1 index com muitas urls. deve ser isso então

Comment: Gostei bastante de sua resposta, vai me ajudar no futuro. Mas ainda não consigo pegar apenas a parte que quero, pois quero pegar apenas  o conteúdo que vai de <div id="content" class="mw-body" role="main"> até <span class="mw-headline" id="Ver_tamb.C3.A9m">Ver também</span>

Comment: eu estava tentando dessa forma preg_match_all("/<div id="content" class="mw-body" role="main">(.*?)<span class="mw-headline" id="Ver_tamb.C3.A9m">Ver também<\/span>/",$content,$matches)